# How to avoid unresolved symbol with clj-kond when using hugSQL def-db-fns macro?

Tags: clojure, hugsql, vscode-calva, clj-kondo

I write Clojure using the VS Code [Calva](https://github.com/BetterThanTomorrow/calva) extension, which uses [clj-kondo](https://github.com/borkdude/clj-kondo) to perform static analysis of my code.

I'm using [HugSQL](https://www.hugsql.org/) to create Clojure functions from SQL queries and statements.

I'm aware that I could handle the database connection and the HugSQL integration with a library like [conman](https://github.com/luminus-framework/conman), infact I used it in the past and I like it, but this time I wanted to keep things vanilla and talk to HugSQL myself.

HugSQL's `def-db-fns` macro takes a SQL file and creates Clojure functions based on the SQL queries and statements contained in that file.

My code below works, but clj-kondo complains that `seed-mytable!` is an unresolved symbol.

```
(ns my-app.db
  "This namespace represents the bridge between the database world and the clojure world."
  (:require [environ.core :refer [env]]
            [hugsql.core :as hugsql]
            [nano-id.core :refer [nano-id]]))

;; This create the function seed-mytable!, but clj-kondo doesn't (cannot?) know it.
(hugsql/def-db-fns "sql/mytable.sql")

;; The functions created by HugSQL can accept a db-spec, a connection, a connection pool,
;; or a transaction object. Let's keep it simple and use a db-spec for a SQLite database.
(def db-spec {:classname "org.sqlite.JDBC"
              :subprotocol "sqlite"
              :subname (env :database-subname)})

(defn db-seed
  "Populate the table with some fakes."
  []
  (let [fakes [[(nano-id) "First fake title" "First fake content"]
               [(nano-id) "Second fake title" "Second fake content"]]]

    ;; clj-kondo complains that seed-my-table! is an unresolved symbol
    (seed-mytable! db-spec {:fakes fakes})))
```

I understand why clj-kondo complains: `seed-mytable!` is not defined anywhere, it's "injected" in this namespace when calling the `def-db-fns` macro.

Is there a way to tell clj-kondo that after calling the `hugsql/def-db-fns` macro the symbol does indeed exist?

Probably it's not that useful, but this is the SQL file I'm loading with HugSQL.

```
-- :name seed-mytable!
-- :command :execute
-- :result :affected
-- :doc Seed the `mytable` table with some fakes.
INSERT INTO mytable (id, title, content)
VALUES :t*:fakes;
```

Comment: Of course I could add something like `(defn seed-mytable! [db params] nil)` and have that evaluated before `(hugsql/def-db-fns "sql/mytable.sql")`, so clj-kondo would stop complaining. But that doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the clj-kondo [documentation](https://github.com/borkdude/clj-kondo/blob/master/doc/config.md):

Sometimes vars are introduced by executing macros, e.g. when using [HugSQL](https://github.com/layerware/hugsql)'s `def-db-fns`. You can suppress warnings about these vars by using `declare`. Example:

```clj
(ns hugsql-example
  (:require [hugsql.core :as hugsql]))

(declare select-things)

;; this will define a var #'select-things:
(hugsql/def-db-fns "select_things.sql")

(defn get-my-things [conn params]
  (select-things conn params))
```

If the amount of symbols introduced by HugSQL becomes too unwieldy, consider
introducing a separate namespace in which HugSQL generates the vars:
`foo.db.hugsql`. You can then refer to this namespace from `foo.db` with
`(require '[foo.db.hugsql :as sql]) (sql/insert! ...)` and clj-kondo will not
complain about this. If it does, you can add `{:linters {:unresolved-var {:exclude [my-hugsql.functions-ns]}}}` to your config.